# pitch someone a proposition?

Tags: writing-style

I'm wondering whether the following phrase is *stylistically* appropriate:

I'd like to pitch you a proposition.

Specifically, I'd like to know whether "pitch" goes well with "proposition."

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I think typically one pitches an idea. The whole pitching of the idea ***is*** the proposition.

Comment: It's a bit awkward, but might be idiomatic in limited contexts, such as when presenting to a venture capitalist.

Comment: @HotLicks What makes you think it might be idiomatic when one presents it to a venture capitalist, while you acknowledge it's a bit awkward?

Comment: @Apollyon - All sorts of awkward lingo is idiomatic in "business-speak".

Comment: @HotLicks What makes you think it's a bit awkward? Could it be that "pitch" in this sense is informal whereas "proposition," a Latinate word, is a bit formal?

Comment: Normally one wouldn't say "pitch you" in that sense.

Comment: @HotLicks Alright. What about "pitch a proposition to you"? Here, "you" is not the direct object of "pitch". Still awkward to you?

Comment: That's better..

Comment: @HotLicks Apart from that, do you feel it awkward to use "pitch" and "proposition" together?

Comment: Generally speaking, "pitch" and "proposition" are regarded (in some senses) as near synonyms, so using them together sounds redundant.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes! That is it. I couldn't really put my fingers on why it sounded awkward. They both nearly mean the same thing! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, even in cases where the particular senses used may not be synonyms, using two words together that are in some sense synonyms will tend to sound awkward.  In your case the senses used are pretty close in meaning, making the awkward sensation worse.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not seem *stylistically* appropriate or sound idiomatic. The reason I think is, as @HotLicks suggested, ***pitch*** and ***propose*** almost convey the same idea here therefore sounds a bit off -

*"to put forth something"*.

Generally, we "[***pitch/propose an idea***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pitch)"

So

> She pitched her idea to me over a business lunch.

You can also - "***Put*** your [***proposition***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proposition) ***to*** someone:"

> I've put my proposition to the company director for his consideration.

You can also "[***Put something forward***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-sth-sb-forward?q=put%20forth)": The *something* here being an idea/proposal/argument.

> - to state an idea or opinion, or to suggest a plan or person, for other people to consider:
>
> The proposals that you have ***put forward*** deserve serious consideration.
>
> I wasn't convinced by any of the arguments that he ***put forward***.
>
> Many suggestions have been ***put forward***, but a decision is unlikely until after next year's general election.

You can also [***Put Forth***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/put--forth?s=t) something:

> - to propose; present:
>
> A new interpretation of the doctrine has been put forth.

Comment: May I ask why you find "pitch someone a proposition" awkward? Could it be that "pitch" in this sense is informal whereas "proposition," a Latinate word, is a bit formal?

Comment: No, to be honest I don't think that is the reason i find it awkward (although there might be a subconscious element to it). The reason I 'think' I find it awkward is simply because I have never heard it. Just to check usage I used Google Ngram - for phrase - *"pitch and idea"* - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pitch+an+idea&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpitch%20an%20idea%3B%2Cc0
An Ngram of *'pitch a proposition'* fails to generate any graph, none. That's a huge difference. Though I agree we shouldn't read too much into it.

Answer (score -2):

Having heard two users say that this is not the norm, I say go with it.

While it might not be popular usage, it is well within the parameters of the definitions of the principals.  If you said that phrase to me, you'd have my attention.

Comment: The OP asked  *" I'd like to know whether "pitch" goes well with "proposition."* I think there's only one answer to that as far as I am concerned.

Comment: And my answer is yes, I appreciate this style.  Very much.  So no, sir.  There is not only one answer.

Comment: I think you read me wrong. I didn't mean to say that what you said is wrong or invalid. I said that, OP asked for how well that two words go together, I said they don't go that well. You might like that usage but it isn't popular (even you conceded that in your answer). So there is only one answer to that particular question, that is "the two words doesn't go that well together" or the "usage isn't that popular (in your words)". That is what I was pointing at. 
By the way the (-1) was not from me, but I understand why one would give that. Cheers!

Comment: The two questions you quoted are not equivalent.  This is not common, and so may be inferred that it is not stylistically appropriate.  My argument is that while it is not a phrase you might hear, I offer that it does work.  I feel it does have a certain style.  As I said, if someone were to say it, they would have my attention.  Instead of having me question myself with inner dialogue about style choice.  Cheers.

Comment: The assumption of my argument was that - *if a word or phrase sounds natural/idiomatic/goes well together, that's because enough people use it and is accepted as a norm (hence popular)*. Anyway, as you think it might work, I am willing to accept that it might work for other people as well. So, I guess the OP should decide or wait for further input from other people. Cheers!